# Can´t add objects to mutable array which returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I´m doing an app and I can´t get a mutable array to accept objects. I´v tried setting breakpoints to see what´s happening but it keeps saying that the mutable array is nil. Does anyone has an answer?
My code:

```
- (void)save:(id) sender {

    // All the values about the product
    NSString *product = self.productTextField.text;
    NSString *partNumber = self.partNumberTextField.text;
    NSString *price = self.priceTextField.text;
    NSString *quantity = self.quantityTextField.text;
    NSString *weigh = self.weighTextField.text;
    NSString *file = [self filePath];

    //Singleton class object
    Object *newObject = [[Object alloc] init];
    newObject.product = product;
    newObject.partNumber = partNumber;
    newObject.price = price;
    newObject.quantity = quantity;
    newObject.weigh = weigh;

    //Array declaration
    mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: file];
    [mutableArray addObject:newObject];
    [mutableArray writeToFile:file atomically:YES];

 }
```

Comment: are you sure of having declared NSMutableArray in .h file ? Also check the mutableArray memory whether it gets allocates to it or not, then you would be easily able to trace out the issue.

Answer (score 3):

While initWithContentsOfFile: can be called on an NSMutableArray, it was inherited from NSArray. The return value is an NSArray which is not mutable. If you want to add objects to your mutable array, you have to do something like this:

```
mutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file] mutableCopy];
[mutableArray addObject:newObject];
[mutableArray writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
```

Now, the addObject: call should work.

Best regards.

Comment: Strangely enough, my experiments show that `initWithContentsOfFile:` always returns a mutable array: `id a = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:@"file"]; BOOL x = [a isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]];` reports that "x == YES". (Tried with Xcode 4.5 on iOS Simulator.)

Answer (score 1):

`[NSMutableArray initWithContentsOfFile:]` [returns nil by default if the file can't be opened or parsed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithContentsOfFile%3a). Are you sure the file you're loading exists and is formatted correctly?

Comment: Reading over your code again, is `mutableArray` a member variable on your object? Are you initializing that (or possibly changing that) somewhere else? Make sure you're setting a breakpoint directly *after* calling `initWithContentsOfFile:` to see what it's being set to.

Comment: @EduardoFont: In your question you say "...  it keeps saying that the mutable array is nil", and in your above comment you say "Xcode says it's not nil". So is `mutableArray` nil or not? You can also check the return value of `writeToFile:`.

Comment: Agree with Martin,  i think here return NO . apple said [writeToFile:atomically:] "returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects"

Comment: The mutable array is nil but the file and the other array are not nil

Comment: @SvenTan you were right, my object was not a property list object but now that I´m trying to code it, but the debugger sais it can´t read the data that I´m loading from the plist I saved the object. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with break point on

```
mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: file];
```

Line. Move your cursor on `mutableArray` if it shows you `__NSArrayI` that means it is an immutable array i.e. you cant update it and if it shows you `__NSArrayM` that means it is a mutable array and you can update this array.
In your case you're getting immutable array thats why you cant update it.
So you have two way to get mutable Array from this file -

**Method:1**

```
mutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file] mutableCopy];
```

**Method:2**

```
NSArray *anyArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: file];
mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:anyArray];
```

In both case `mutableArray` woud be a mutable Array. You can update it.